# Lightroom 5: export photo with NO keywords

Tags: lightroom, keywords

I'm hoping to find a way to export my photos without ANY of the keywords, without having to go through the keyword list and turn off exporting for each one individually. I found this thread: [How can I batch-remove the not-for-export flag on Lightroom keywords?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12651/how-can-i-batch-remove-the-not-for-export-flag-on-lightroom-keywords) that seems relevant, but it's also two years old. I'm hoping there's a better way included in the software by this point.

Does anyone know if this is possible without resorting to using a script or tampering with the DB directly?

Thanks in advance for any pointers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the export dialog, find the Metadata section:

[image]

Change the include selection to be either "Copyright Only" or "Copyright and Contact Info Only". Your photos will not include any Keywords or other EXIF information. If you wanted to retain the EXIF information, but still exclude keywords, I believe you have to export with the keywords and then use a command line tool like exiftool to remove them after export:

```
exiftool -IPTC:Keywords= -XMP:Subject= -ext jpg -overwrite_original .
```

Comment: Good call on exiftool - I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Lightroom, if you only want to exclude certain keywords (like say the name of a child) you can do that by right-clicking on the keyword in the metadata list and exclude it from all exports.  This allows you to still export images with keywords while excluding certain ones.

To exclude all keywords from export, just select "Copyright Only" or "Copyright and Contact Info Only" from within the Metadata options area in the Export window.